# query_posts and pagination, still stuck after much research

Tags: query-posts, pagination

I need to paginate some custom posts...I can’t see why but I’m getting 404’s when going to the next page. Here’s my code:

```
$paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;

query_posts( array( 'post_type' => 's_stories', 'posts_per_page' => 4 , 'paged'=>$paged) );

if (have_posts()){ 

while (have_posts()) { the_post(); ?>


<div class="post">
<h2 class="title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
<?php the_excerpt(); ?>

</div> <!-- end post -->

<div class="clear"></div>

<?php } }  ?>

<div class="paging">


    <div style="float:left; font-weight:bold"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Previous Story') ?></div>
    <div style="float:right; font-weight:bold"><?php previous_posts_link('Next Story &raquo;') ?></div>

</div>
```

I’ve got the ‘paged’ value and the post navigation, any idea what’s up now....?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Don't use `query_posts`](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/50762/9364). This is a classic example of what happens when you do :)

Basically, when WordPress receives an url, it interprets this as a query - it then queries the database to find the results (if any) and serves up an appropriate template (such as 404.php in the case of no results).

If it happens to reach your template page - it's then told to discard that query, and start a new one (which is wasteful) and will break pagination.

Basically pagination adds the `paged` query variable to the current url - this new url (which should take you to page 2, say) - forms the basis of the query to recieve page 2 - but the url in the address bar isn't the content you are after (because you discard that and start a new query with `query_posts`. The end result is that a query, that you don't really want, is performed and turns up no results, so the 404 template is served and the template with your `query_posts` is never reached.

Have a look at the above linked post for alternatives to `query_post`, but as this is the 'main query' (the query based on the recieved url) you want to be using [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone. I’ve just been looking at pre_get_posts, would this be used just on this page template I’m working on? It’s for use on one custom post type, so I guess I could just drop it in functions.php. Anyway, no luck with the query yet (with pre_get_posts), I was thinking something like: $query->query_vars['post_type'] = 's_stories’; ...?

Comment: Something like that would work - what exactly are you after? When do you want to display the `s_stories`? WordPress automatically generates an 'archive' of post types with `www.example.com?post_type=s_stories` (and you can have pretty permalink equivalent)

Comment: Ok, so I’m testing via the template. I need 4 posts per page from my custom post type, with pagination. Here’s what I have so far:

Comment: `function s_stories( $query ) {
 global $wp_query; 
 if($query->is_main_query()){
  if(is_page_template('student-stories.php')){
  $query->set('posts_per_page',4);
  $query->set('post_type','s_stories');  
  }
 }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 's_stories' );`

Comment: Why not use the post type archive that WordPress produces? See my comment above.

Comment: Well, I could make a template for just this post type using “archive-s_stories.php”...although this won’t work for some reason!

Comment: Ok, so I’ve got the archive template working properly. ‘has_archive’ wasn’t turned on in the plugin this website is using...I usually do this myself and overlooked it this time! Thanks for your input, I clearly needed to learn about pre_get_posts and will be using it as much as possible from now on.

Comment: This post reminded me that I could just drop the static page and use archive-{custom-post-type}.php and saved me from tearing my hair out..!

Answer (score 2):

Try this...

```
<?php
  global $paged; global $wp_query;
  $temp = $wp_query; $wp_query= null; $wp_query = new WP_Query();
  $wp_query->query('showposts=XX&post_type=POST_TYPE_NAME'.'&paged='.$paged);
  while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : $wp_query->the_post(); 
?>

    // do your content output here...

<?php endwhile; ?>

   // do pagination here...

<?php $wp_query = null; $wp_query = $temp;?>
```

Comment: Hi Userabuser, just wanted to say thanks for taking the time to write, I should have this sorted now. Dan

Answer (score 1):

`query_posts()` should not be used in general and especially if you are trying to mess with pagination.

Both pagination and 404 logic happens before template file (and `query_posts()` in it) even starts to load.

To tweak main query of the page one of the best options is to use [`pre_get_posts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) hook.